# Is there an alternative function for unnest_longer()?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, unnest

found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59192970/23061034

Is there any function that works like unnest_longer()? I am trying to run the following lines of codes but an error keeps occurring when trying to unnest.

```
df %>%
  filter(n() > 2L, .by = sn2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sn3, values_from = dml1_5:leisure, 
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest_longer(dml1_5_1:leisure_2, keep_empty = TRUE)
```

Error in `unnest_longer()`:
! In row 9, can't recycle input of size 4 to size 2.

Desired output:

| sn2 | leisure.1 | hmonth.1 | hyear.1 | leisure.2 | hmonth.2 | hyear.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 227 | 230 | 6 | 2000 | 540 | 6 | 2000 |
| 227 | 130 | 6 | 2000 | 170 | 6 | 2000 |
| 250 | 370 | 6 | 2000 | 380 | 6 | 2000 |
| 250 | 380 | 6 | 2000 | 190 | 6 | 2000 |
| 294 | 120 | 6 | 2000 | 210 | 6 | 2000 |
| 294 | 200 | 6 | 2000 | 310 | 6 | 2000 |
| 307 | 130 | 7 | 2000 | 220 | 7 | 2000 |
| 307 | 480 | 7 | 2000 | 270 | 7 | 2000 |

Data:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(sn2 = structure(c(227, 227, 227, 227, 249, 249, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 294, 294, 294, 294, 307, 307, 307, 307, 318, 
318, 341, 341, 352, 352, 352, 352, 363, 363, 385, 385, 385, 385, 
409, 409, 455, 455, 455, 455, 535, 535, 535, 535, 568, 568, 580, 
580, 591, 591, 591, 591, 661, 661, 683, 683, 718, 718, 741, 741, 
741, 741, 763, 763, 763, 763, 809, 809, 809, 809, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 37, 37, 37, 37, 93, 93, 117, 117, 117, 139, 139, 151, 151, 
162, 162, 162, 162, 210, 210, 210, 210, 221, 221, 221, 221, 254, 
254, 254, 254, 265, 265, 265, 265, 301, 301, 301, 301, 345, 345, 
356, 356, 356, 356, 390, 390, 390, 390, 517, 517, 562, 562, 573, 
573, 573, 573, 595, 595, 595, 595, 610, 610, 621, 621, 621, 621, 
632, 632, 643, 643, 712, 712, 712, 712, 723, 723, 723, 723, 745, 
745, 745, 745, 789, 789, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 42, 
42, 75, 75, 86, 86, 86, 86, 100, 100, 100, 100, 155, 155, 155, 
155, 166, 166, 166, 166, 214, 214, 225, 225, 225, 225, 247, 247, 
247, 247, 258, 258, 281, 281, 316, 316, 316, 316, 327, 327, 338, 
338, 361, 361, 383, 383, 394, 394, 394, 394, 422, 422, 422, 422, 
433, 433, 433, 433, 444, 444, 444, 444, 466, 466, 499, 499, 499, 
499, 524, 524, 524, 524, 568, 568, 568, 568, 580, 580, 580, 580, 
591, 591, 591, 591, 649, 649, 649, 649, 672, 672, 672, 672, 683, 
683, 683, 683, 707, 707, 707, 707, 730, 730, 730, 730, 741, 741, 
741, 741, 785, 785, 785, 785, 809, 809, 809, 809, 59, 59, 59, 
59, 82, 82, 82, 82, 106, 106, 106, 106, 117, 117, 117, 117, 128, 
128, 151, 151, 151, 151, 162, 162, 162, 162, 173, 173, 173, 173, 
184, 184, 184, 184, 221, 221, 232, 232, 232, 232, 254, 254, 254, 
254, 265, 265, 276, 276, 298, 298, 298, 298, 345, 345, 345, 345, 
367, 367, 367, 367, 389, 389, 389, 389, 528, 528, 528, 528, 539, 
539, 539, 539, 551, 551, 584, 584), label = "household number", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    sn3 = structure(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
    1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "person number", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    dml1_5 = structure(c(70, 30, 170, 30, 180, 250, 230, 210, 
    170, 30, 80, 110, 10, 40, 30, 420, 20, 270, 170, 160, 60, 
    70, 90, 10, 380, 20, 360, 170, 70, 120, 190, 110, 60, 230, 
    0, 0, 0, 130, 10, 70, 590, 160, 220, 260, 140, 30, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 70, 110, 60, 0, 70, 290, 80, 0, 70, 140, 140, 150, 
    360, 380, 20, 90, 30, 30, 40, 100, 110, 110, 70, 100, 0, 
    70, 110, 70, 50, 170, 0, 610, 240, 160, 250, 70, 170, 70, 
    200, 0, 0, 20, 60, 150, 10, 10, 30, 250, 230, 150, 0, 90, 
    100, 0, 10, 270, 0, 330, 60, 0, 40, 0, 0, 50, 30, 0, 10, 
    60, 30, 0, 30, 70, 230, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 0, 420, 140, 50, 
    140, 40, 70, 10, 30, 0, 360, 50, 660, 180, 190, 100, 120, 
    110, 160, 110, 210, 40, 30, 0, 90, 10, 0, 170, 0, 310, 10, 
    270, 30, 270, 40, 10, 0, 80, 90, 0, 80, 60, 70, 250, 250, 
    80, 170, 60, 220, 210, 240, 0, 0, 110, 0, 330, 30, 40, 10, 
    60, 0, 90, 50, 130, 140, 90, 170, 60, 290, 80, 0, 0, 0, 180, 
    60, 0, 40, 0, 130, 110, 130, 0, 0, 40, 80, 0, 0, 10, 0, 80, 
    210, 100, 90, 30, 70, 60, 30, 60, 10, 0, 20, 10, 10, 0, 0, 
    0, 170, 220, 50, 40, 0, 0, 180, 30, 350, 90, 30, 90, 0, 0, 
    110, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 270, 80, 430, 10, 130, 100, 0, 20, 
    130, 60, 0, 400, 50, 0, 10, 70, 120, 220, 160, 240, 70, 0, 
    120, 0, 0, 300, 70, 210, 20, 0, 0, 0, 210, 20, 60, 0, 30, 
    300, 0, 0, 40, 140, 0, 40, 0, 80, 40, 0, 0, 0, 60, 310, 60, 
    350, 190, 0, 40, 60, 60, 70, 30, 0, 180, 30, 100, 30, 80, 
    40, 30, 70, 0, 140, 20, 10, 50, 0, 230, 120, 90, 150, 30, 
    280, 10, 310, 0, 10, 0, 0, 90, 0, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 20, 
    70, 180, 30), label = "main activity - social life & entertainment (mins per day)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    dml1_6 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 370, 0, 0, 0, 160, 
    0, 100, 0, 0, 190, 0, 130, 0, 200, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 20, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    50, 140, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 80, 
    40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 50, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 60, 
    0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 
    0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 230, 540, 100, 0, 
    90, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 170, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "main activity - sports & outdoor activities (mins per day)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    dml1_7 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 210, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 130, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 390, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 20, 0, 0, 230, 0, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 170, 10, 
    10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 30, 30, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 30, 
    20, 0, 0, 180, 0, 240, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 180, 30, 40, 20, 
    20, 0, 10, 40, 0, 0, 190, 180, 150, 30, 60, 0, 0, 0, 20, 
    10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 120, 70, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 80, 
    0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 10, 10, 110, 110, 120, 10, 120, 70, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    10, 10, 0, 0, 90, 190, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 10, 
    420, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 40, 0, 0, 40, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 140, 0, 0, 
    140, 0, 170, 790, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 60, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 330, 40), label = "main activity - hobbies & games (mins per day)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    dml1_8 = structure(c(160, 100, 370, 140, 40, 230, 140, 170, 
    210, 130, 40, 90, 200, 250, 100, 60, 200, 0, 170, 60, 10, 
    250, 80, 130, 240, 0, 150, 290, 70, 40, 70, 0, 20, 0, 370, 
    230, 350, 0, 150, 50, 50, 240, 270, 460, 150, 180, 50, 60, 
    10, 20, 300, 270, 120, 80, 170, 60, 10, 40, 60, 20, 140, 
    90, 260, 0, 260, 100, 140, 40, 20, 120, 100, 240, 10, 300, 
    220, 140, 220, 140, 10, 100, 250, 130, 150, 280, 170, 320, 
    240, 190, 180, 80, 100, 90, 100, 40, 170, 30, 270, 210, 0, 
    150, 120, 130, 260, 140, 340, 120, 170, 50, 320, 110, 110, 
    250, 230, 370, 180, 120, 80, 130, 190, 420, 500, 30, 10, 
    110, 310, 0, 230, 500, 80, 180, 240, 350, 140, 80, 100, 330, 
    360, 100, 150, 150, 100, 100, 70, 270, 270, 130, 140, 80, 
    230, 150, 200, 270, 620, 80, 10, 250, 210, 150, 420, 0, 120, 
    0, 290, 230, 340, 150, 60, 180, 230, 170, 180, 200, 10, 510, 
    250, 30, 0, 240, 80, 0, 0, 120, 100, 0, 0, 310, 230, 320, 
    200, 390, 410, 310, 320, 170, 220, 140, 90, 0, 160, 0, 150, 
    280, 180, 370, 310, 130, 90, 380, 300, 210, 280, 200, 70, 
    0, 60, 160, 230, 50, 120, 150, 120, 120, 150, 170, 400, 310, 
    470, 80, 70, 280, 170, 400, 480, 560, 510, 10, 50, 80, 90, 
    190, 250, 160, 110, 80, 90, 20, 10, 90, 140, 140, 50, 90, 
    70, 170, 140, 80, 180, 80, 210, 150, 220, 280, 140, 0, 210, 
    250, 0, 0, 560, 170, 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 0, 90, 30, 
    160, 30, 50, 160, 180, 130, 330, 140, 670, 250, 100, 240, 
    180, 40, 140, 290, 150, 320, 90, 350, 30, 80, 260, 240, 120, 
    180, 280, 300, 0, 100, 80, 30, 220, 330, 170, 20, 170, 50, 
    250, 110, 260, 110, 130, 310, 100, 160, 230, 150, 230, 130, 
    330, 160, 290, 280, 240, 190, 160, 180, 270, 410, 250, 260, 
    250, 420, 60, 0, 150, 200, 140, 170, 190, 170, 120, 480), label = "main activity - mass media (mins per day)", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    hmonth = structure(c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    6, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 11, 11, 11, 11, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 
    10, 10, 10), label = "month of household interview", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(january = 1, 
    february = 2, march = 3, april = 4, may = 5, june = 6, july = 7, 
    august = 8, september = 9, october = 10, november = 11, december = 12
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    hyear = structure(c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000), label = "year of household interview", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    leisure = c(230, 130, 540, 170, 430, 480, 370, 380, 380, 
    190, 120, 200, 210, 310, 130, 480, 220, 270, 340, 260, 90, 
    320, 170, 140, 620, 390, 510, 460, 140, 450, 260, 210, 80, 
    230, 560, 620, 480, 130, 360, 120, 640, 430, 490, 720, 310, 
    210, 50, 60, 10, 20, 460, 380, 270, 170, 240, 370, 90, 40, 
    130, 160, 300, 240, 620, 380, 280, 190, 170, 70, 150, 220, 
    210, 580, 110, 400, 300, 210, 330, 210, 60, 270, 250, 740, 
    560, 450, 430, 430, 410, 260, 380, 80, 100, 110, 160, 190, 
    180, 70, 310, 520, 260, 300, 120, 220, 410, 280, 400, 390, 
    190, 380, 380, 140, 180, 250, 230, 450, 210, 120, 90, 190, 
    250, 530, 590, 100, 240, 290, 310, 240, 230, 650, 260, 600, 
    380, 580, 310, 160, 190, 360, 390, 110, 550, 200, 760, 470, 
    440, 520, 420, 330, 350, 190, 500, 210, 240, 270, 720, 150, 
    10, 540, 340, 530, 500, 270, 150, 270, 330, 250, 340, 230, 
    150, 180, 310, 230, 250, 450, 260, 590, 420, 100, 220, 450, 
    320, 0, 0, 230, 100, 350, 120, 430, 240, 380, 200, 540, 460, 
    440, 480, 260, 390, 200, 380, 80, 160, 0, 150, 460, 240, 
    370, 350, 130, 220, 500, 440, 320, 390, 360, 160, 180, 130, 
    270, 230, 130, 330, 250, 220, 160, 220, 230, 590, 560, 480, 
    90, 90, 440, 180, 400, 480, 560, 680, 350, 110, 540, 340, 
    190, 430, 190, 460, 280, 140, 110, 90, 90, 250, 140, 50, 
    120, 70, 170, 140, 350, 260, 510, 230, 280, 360, 280, 160, 
    400, 870, 350, 400, 140, 560, 180, 280, 150, 220, 160, 240, 
    70, 0, 270, 0, 90, 330, 230, 310, 70, 160, 180, 130, 580, 
    480, 730, 430, 270, 540, 350, 830, 180, 430, 150, 360, 90, 
    430, 130, 110, 260, 240, 180, 490, 340, 650, 190, 100, 120, 
    90, 280, 400, 200, 20, 350, 80, 350, 210, 340, 150, 160, 
    380, 100, 470, 250, 160, 280, 130, 560, 280, 430, 440, 270, 
    470, 170, 490, 270, 420, 250, 260, 340, 420, 360, 0, 150, 
    260, 140, 300, 210, 240, 630, 550)), row.names = c(NA, -355L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`3492` = 3492L, 
`3493` = 3493L, `3494` = 3494L, `3495` = 3495L, `3496` = 3496L, 
`3497` = 3497L, `3498` = 3498L, `3499` = 3499L, `3500` = 3500L, 
`3501` = 3501L, `3508` = 3508L, `3509` = 3509L, `3510` = 3510L, 
`3511` = 3511L, `3512` = 3512L, `3513` = 3513L, `3518` = 3518L, 
`3519` = 3519L, `3520` = 3520L, `3521` = 3521L, `3522` = 3522L, 
`3523` = 3523L, `3524` = 3524L, `3525` = 3525L), class = "omit"))
```

Comment: What does the error message say? I've run code with data and am not getting any errors on my system.

Comment: ```Error in `unnest_longer()`:
! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 14 to size 12.``` @AndyBaxter

Comment: You can try `keep_empty = TRUE` in the `unnest_longer` call - it should put NAs in where there are no values in rows? (your filter statement in the above example stops the error coming up - it's when there are an uneven number of nested values across a single row)

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense, but I'm still getting an error. I've updated the dataset  to include more observations. Could you possibly run the codes and see whether you're also getting the same error? @AndyBaxter

Comment: this code works for me also

Comment: create a small example where your problem is reproduced with a clean environment, possibly by whittling down your original dataset

Answer (score 2):

Using your dataset above, adding `keep_empty = TRUE` works for me to unnest all rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sn3, values_from = leisure:hyear, 
              values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest_longer(leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE) 

#> # A tibble: 353 × 10
#>      sn2 dml1_5 dml1_6 dml1_7 dml1_8  hmonth leisure_1 leisure_2 hyear_1 hyear_2
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <hvn_l>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1   227     70      0      0    160       6       230        NA    2000      NA
#>  2   227     30      0      0    100       6       130        NA    2000      NA
#>  3   227    170      0      0    370       6        NA       540      NA    2000
#>  4   227     30      0      0    140       6        NA       170      NA    2000
#>  5   249    180      0    210     40       6       430        NA    2000      NA
#>  6   249    250      0      0    230       6       480        NA    2000      NA
#>  7   250    230      0      0    140       6       370        NA    2000      NA
#>  8   250    210      0      0    170       6       380        NA    2000      NA
#>  9   250    170      0      0    210       6        NA       380      NA    2000
#> 10   250     30     30      0    130       6        NA       190      NA    2000
#> # ℹ 343 more rows
```

Comment: Seems like the error only occurs on my end... odd... is there any for me to achieve the same output without using unnest?

Comment: Ah I see, how I've got the same error on your updated pivot call. Will see how that works

Answer (score 2):

The problem happens when the number of values within any one cell (in a row) is not unambiguously-recyclable with the other columns to unnest.

As an example,

```r
quux <- df %>%
  filter(n() > 2L, .by = sn2) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sn3, values_from = leisure:hyear, 
              values_fn = list) %>%
  mutate(
    leisure_1 = c(list(rep(leisure_1[[1]], 3)), leisure_1[-1]),
    hyear_1 = c(list(rep(hyear_1[[1]], 2)), hyear_1[-1])
  ) %>%
  head()
quux
# # A tibble: 6 × 10
#     sn2 dml1_5 dml1_6 dml1_7 dml1_8 hmonth    leisure_1 leisure_2 hyear_1   hyear_2  
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl+lbl> <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
# 1   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]  <dbl [3]> <NULL>    <dbl [2]> <NULL>   
# 2   227     30      0      0    100 6 [june]  <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>   
# 3   227    170      0      0    370 6 [june]  <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]>
# 4   227     30      0      0    140 6 [june]  <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]>
# 5   250    230      0      0    140 6 [june]  <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>   
# 6   250    210      0      0    170 6 [june]  <dbl [1]> <NULL>    <dbl [1]> <NULL>   

unnest_longer(quux, leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE) 
# Error in unnest_longer(quux, leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE) : 
#   In row 1, can't recycle input of size 3 to size 2.
```

We can see that on row 1, `leisure_1` has 3 values whereas `hyear_1` has only 2. If one of them had only 1, then the tidyverse rules of recycling ("1 or n") would allow it to work without error. (In constrast, native R's recycling rules are sloppy, allowing length-4 and length-2 to be compatible since 4 is an even multiple of 2. This can be used in clever hacks, but in my experience more often than not results in incorrect expansions/recycling, and should always be avoided. I think others agree, since tidyverse recycling rules require that all values to be combined in this fashion must only be length-1 or the same length as the longest.)

Without knowing the true context of observational alignment of your data, we are able to impose some same-length-ness by extending the short column to be the length of the longer.

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(
    len_1 = pmax(lengths(leisure_1), lengths(hyear_1)),
    len_2 = pmax(lengths(leisure_2), lengths(hyear_2)),
    across(c(leisure_1, hyear_1), ~ Map(`length<-`, .x, len_1)), 
    across(c(leisure_2, hyear_2), ~ Map(`length<-`, .x, len_2))
  ) %>%
  unnest_longer(leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 8 × 12
#     sn2 dml1_5 dml1_6 dml1_7 dml1_8 hmonth    leisure_1 leisure_2 hyear_1 hyear_2 len_1 len_2
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl+lbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]        230        NA    2000      NA     3     0
# 2   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]        230        NA    2000      NA     3     0
# 3   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]        230        NA      NA      NA     3     0
# 4   227     30      0      0    100 6 [june]        130        NA    2000      NA     1     0
# 5   227    170      0      0    370 6 [june]         NA       540      NA    2000     0     1
# 6   227     30      0      0    140 6 [june]         NA       170      NA    2000     0     1
# 7   250    230      0      0    140 6 [june]        370        NA    2000      NA     1     0
# 8   250    210      0      0    170 6 [june]        380        NA    2000      NA     1     0
```

Notice the change: I had artificially repeated the first `leisure_1` value to be length-3, and the corresponding `hyear_1` to be length-2. Looking at the first three rows, we have two rows where the `leisure_1` and `hyear_1` values correspond find, and the third row has an empty (`NA`) `hyear_1`.

Realize that this preserves all of the data, but might break some assumptions about a row being a complete observation.

---

*Edit*: if you want to drop the extras (that is, if we have 4 in one column and 2 in another, then we'll keep only the first 2 from the column-with-4), then

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(
    len_1 = pmin(lengths(leisure_1), lengths(hyear_1)),
    len_2 = pmin(lengths(leisure_2), lengths(hyear_2)),
    across(c(leisure_1, hyear_1), ~ Map(head, .x, len_1)), 
    across(c(leisure_2, hyear_2), ~ Map(head, .x, len_2))
  ) %>%
  unnest_longer(leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 7 × 12
#     sn2 dml1_5 dml1_6 dml1_7 dml1_8 hmonth    leisure_1 leisure_2 hyear_1 hyear_2 len_1 len_2
#   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl+lbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]        230        NA    2000      NA     2     0
# 2   227     70      0      0    160 6 [june]        230        NA    2000      NA     2     0
# 3   227     30      0      0    100 6 [june]        130        NA    2000      NA     1     0
# 4   227    170      0      0    370 6 [june]         NA       540      NA    2000     0     1
# 5   227     30      0      0    140 6 [june]         NA       170      NA    2000     0     1
# 6   250    230      0      0    140 6 [june]        370        NA    2000      NA     1     0
# 7   250    210      0      0    170 6 [june]        380        NA    2000      NA     1     0
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to push rows 5,6 up to rows 1,2 so that sn2 only has two complete rows of 227, same applies for the entire dataset. (Complete in the sense that every column is filled, as achieved in the answers from these posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78183304/unnest-longer-cant-recycle-input; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181122/keep-all-matched-rows-when-reshaping-from-long-to-wide).

Comment: I understand. Looking at your row 9 (where I get my first error), half of the nested columns (ending with `_1`) have 4 elements, the other half (`_2`) have 2 elements. What do you think should happen in this case? For instance, looking at `dml1_5_*`, how should `c(220, 260, 220, 50)` relate with `c(40, 0)`?

Comment: Is it possible to drop the extra elements and just combine c(220, 260) and c(40,0)?

Comment: "Combine" can be a few things. Sum? Average? Min/Max? String-concatenate? If the latter, realize that this means ALL values in those columns will be strings, not just those rows that have different lengths in the list-columns.

Comment: If you refer to the answer by Allan Cameron, that is exactly what I want (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78181122/keep-all-matched-rows-when-reshaping-from-long-to-wide) The first row of sn3=1 should match the first row of sn3=2 after pivoting from long to wide format. If there are more elements in (ending with ```_1```), then naturally some elements will not be matched. In this case, the unmatched cells (ending with ```_2```) should contain NA which will be dropped.

Comment: That answer does not seem to mention any of the methods I suggested. In the case of row 9, is it your intent to _drop_ some values, so `c(220, 260, 220, 50)` should be retained as `c(220, 260)`?

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned, there are unequal elements. I want to retain 2 elements in ```_1``` if ```_2``` has only 2. I want the number of elements in ```_1``` and ```_2``` to be equal.

Comment: Everything works fine until I ran ```unnest_longer()```. Error in `unnest_longer()`:
! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 14 to size 12.
Backtrace:
 1. ... %>% unnest_longer(leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE)
 2. tidyr::unnest_longer(., leisure_1:hyear_2, keep_empty = TRUE)

Comment: The updated sample data as it stands works, I don't know how that error is happening.